A scene with a video message of a mother dying of cancer
The event revolves around a woman who is haunted by the guilt that she was not by her mother's side when she died. She adored her mother but when she found out that she was dying of a disease (possibly cancer), she could not bring herself to be by her side. She avoids visiting her at the hospital.
Later, at the end she discovers a CD recorded by her mother which tells her that she had told the woman's father to keep her away so that she did not see her in that condition and she does not think less of her for not wanting to come or something to that effect and finally she gets closure and is able to move on.

This could be the Smallville episode Abandoned (Season 10, Episode 8). From an online recap:

Lois is unpacking a box when Clark comes in. He notes that she's reluctant to admit that she moved in, and Lois explains that the box contains her mother's keepsakes, and her father sent her to them. Her mother, Ella, gave them to Lois after she found she had cancer. Lois explains that she never visited her mother during the five weeks she was in the hospital, and never said goodbye to her.
Lois watches her mother's first tape. On it, Ella explains that she asked the Colonel not to bring [Lois and her sister to the hospital] so that they would have happy memories of her. She asks Lois to play the tapes and think of her, and then says not to let the loss of a parent interfere with her chance to find happiness with someone in the future. Ella assures her daughter that she will always love her.

Her mom is played by Teri Hatcher. Here's the entire scene:




Yes that was it.... Thanks a lot... I was wondering for long where i had seen it
